# VBA take user input (integer), and input it into a timer Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, timer, excel-2007

I want to take user input (i.e. " 5 ") and make that into the format of 00:05:00 (hh:mm:ss), where the number inputted is the number of minutes to be used in a timer. The program will then automatically start a timer with that allotted amount of time. The time will be displayed in B10 as is, which needs no formatting, but the timer will be displayed in cell " I1 ".

```
'FUNCTION FOR FORMATTING THE INPUT
Public Function RetTime(IntTime As Integer) As Date
RetTime = TimeSerial(Int(IntTime / 10000), Int((IntTime Mod 10000) / 100), (IntTime Mod 100))
End Function


'ACCEPTING THE TIME INTERVAL
Sub TimeInterval()
TimeIntervals = InputBox("How long for the intervals?")
Range("B10").Value = TimeIntervals
Range("A2").Select

'setting that time interval to the " I1 " cell
I1 = RetTime(TimeIntervals)
Range("I1").Value = I1

NumOfInterval

End Sub


'THE COUNTDOWN TIMER:
Sub StartTimer()
    Future = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Application.OnTime earliestTime:=Future, procedure:="nextTime", _
         schedule:=True
End Sub

'From the formatted input that was placed in "I1", make that into a timer
Sub nextTime()
    Sheet1.Range("I1").TimeValue = Sheet1.Range("I1").TimeValue - TimeValue("00:00:01")
    StartTimer
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime earliestTime:=Future, _
       procedure:="nextTime", schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if they follow the format in the inputbox you can use this code.
in this example user input of 00:05:00 will result in the variable timer = 5

```
Sub ashTime()

   Dim timer As String

   timer = minute(InputBox("Enter minutes as HH:MM:SS"))

   MsgBox timer

End Sub
```